# What is the Linux equivalent of Mac OS X's "Sample Process"?

Tags: linux, profiling

On Mac OS X, you can "sample" a process, which takes a backtrace of every thread in a specified process a specified number of times and then displays what methods are running ([Apple man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sample.1.html), [example output from my Mac](https://bpaste.net/raw/17c3d41b1ee2)).

How does one accomplish this on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/examples/) which has a very similar set of features to Mac OS X's `sample`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try perf utility http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html. It gives callgraph that is nested and explain the time spent in that nest